# Undefined reference during linking using ncurses and cmake

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, ncurses, clion

I am trying to use ncurses in my C++-Program by including the following headers:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <menu.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I am using CLion IDE and this is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(LearnC)

set(CURSES_USE_NCURSES TRUE)
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(LearnC ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(LearnC ${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Compilation goes well however while linking I am getting these errors:

```
[ 20%] Linking CXX executable LearnC
CMakeFiles/LearnC.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
../LearnC/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `initscr'
../LearnC/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `clear'
../LearnC/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `noecho'
../LearnC/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `curs_set'
../LearnC/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cbreak'
../LearnC/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `nl'
../LearnC/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `stdscr'
../LearnC/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `keypad'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From documentation of CMAKE, you need to specify files not directory for target_link_libraries. So something like

```
target_link_libraries(LearnC curses)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries

Comment: In this case (with use of `find_package(Curses)`) library files are listed in *CURSES_LIBRARIES* variable: `target_link_libraries(LearnC ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: This worked. Also adding `-lncurses` to the `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` helped.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I though so too but I've actually tried it and that's why I was getting the error. Using `cmake` v3.x. This was the reason I came to this thread since I didn't want to specify the actual library file manually.